# Is there an equivalent of kable (R) on python?

Tags: python, html-table

I'm trying to add group row and background colors to a table. As i'm new on python I knew Kable from R so I was wondering if there was an equivalent.

Here is an example of what I would like to get out of :

[image: Table from Kable]

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has this feature built in. It is called [style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) You can add all sorts of conditional formattings.

Comment: If you are asking about conditional formattings specifically here are some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203959/conditionally-format-python-pandas-cell). Other than that it really depends on your use case but I'd love to help if you provide more details.