# Is there a way to format cells in a data frame based on conditions on multiple columns?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a dataframe with a few columns (one boolean and one numeric). I want to put conditional formatting using pandas styling since I am going to output my dataframe as html in an email, based on the following conditions: 1. boolean column = Y and 2. numeric column > 0.

For example,

```
col1 col2
 Y    15
 N    0
 Y    0
 N    40
 Y    20
```

In the example above, I want to highlight the first and last row since they meet those conditions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203959/conditionally-format-python-pandas-cell

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. Use lambda expressions to apply conditions and dropna() function to disclude None/NaN values:

```
df["col2"] = df["col2"].apply(lambda x:x if x > 0 else None)
df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x:x if x == 'Y' else None)
df.dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I am looking to use the style function. Essentially to be able to do this df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: red" if Col1 == "Y" and Col2 > 0], axis = 1). Can you please help with the syntax on this?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it worked:

def highlight_color(s):
    if s.Col2 > 0 and s.Col1 == "N":
        return ['background-color: red'] * 7
    else:
        return ['background-color: white'] * 7

df.style.apply(highlight_color, axis=1).render()