# Python Pandas - highlighting cells in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to test if the values of a column are bigger than another specific value of the same data frame.
If a value is bigger, I want to highlight this specific cell.

I tried this:

```py
import pandas as pd

b = pd.DataFrame([[5,7,3],[2,3,4],[8,4,7]])

for i in range(0, len(b)):
    for j in range(0, len(b.columns)):
        if  b.iloc[i][j] >  b.iloc[2][j]:
            b.style.applymap(lambda  x: 'background-color : blue' if b.iloc[i][j] >  b.iloc[2][j] else '') 

b
```

So in this example I want to check if 5 or 7 is bigger than 3 (column 1), 2 or 3 bigger than 4 (column 2) and 8 or 4 is bigger than 7.

It doesn't color anything... I hope someone can help me. Thx in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally format Python pandas cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203959/conditionally-format-python-pandas-cell)

Comment: I've seen this question already… it basically the code is the same but in my case it is not working...

Comment: Interesting.. Can you add a minimal runnable snippet of your code?

Comment: Sorry I had some Problems entering code down here. It's now in the main Question.

Comment: I added a solution that works for me directly in a jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[5,7,8],[2,3,4],[8,4,9]])

def highlight(s):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series.
    '''
    is_max = s >= s[2]
    return ['background-color: blue' if v else '' for v in is_max]

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=0)
```

[image]

Note that the solution is based on the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203959/conditionally-format-python-pandas-cell) we discussed. The main change is the condition inside the highlight function. Using `applymap` works on a single cell each time, and has no access to its location in the dataframe. Using `apply` works on a single row each time and enables comparing to cell in the same row and different column.

Comment: But I don't want to highlight the maximum of each row. I want to highlight in  a huge data frame column by column the values which are bigger than the last value in this column. And changing applymap tp apply doen't work either..

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I changed the `axis` in the last line of code from `1` to `0`. This makes it work on columns rather than rows.

Comment: Now it Looks good! Hopefully I can adapt this to my data frame and use it in the loops..
Tank you!

Comment: You don't need loops to run it, it implicitly contains them inside. Working with `for` loops on data frames, especially when they are large is usually a bad practice. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Ooh you're true. Okay now I need to mark values bigger then last value of the column and smaller then second last value of the column and this column by column. I guess I Need a loop to automatically do this for every column?

Comment: Take a look at [Pandas Style Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html), they create an auxiliary function like the `highlight` function in our example, and apply them one after the other on the same data frame. If you don't manage by youself you may edit the question and I'll change the solution accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229936/discussion-between-shir-and-seaseaess).

Comment: okay thank you for all the informations, the codes and the link. I'll try by myself and eventually come back to you. :)