# High light cell that contain certain text for 1 column openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jack has a cat | jack aa |
| 2 | jim has a car | jack ab |
| 3 | jack has a dog | jim cc |
| 4 | jack has a house | jim dd |

I want to high light cell that got Jack with color red, Jim with yellow
what I came up with but have no outcome

```
def highlight_jack(ser):
       color= "red" if 'jack' in str(ser)  else ''
       return f"background-color: {color}"

def highlight_jim(ser):
       color= "yellow" if 'jim' in str(ser)  else ''
       return f"background-color: {color}"

df_merge.style.applymap(highlight_jack, subset=['B'])
df_merge.style.applymap(highlight_jim, subset=['B'])

df_merge.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= sheet, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally format Python pandas cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203959/conditionally-format-python-pandas-cell)

Comment: Jack has a capital J in the name. You would probably want to test if 'jack' in str(ser).lower()

Comment: @Tomerikoo
`df_merge.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: red" if 'jack' in str(v) else "" for v in x], axis = 1, subset['B'])` is this the right approach ? Still no outcome

Comment: @Lexpj Just fixed the table, text are matched